# Unknown plugin "transform-function-bind" specified in "path" at 0,

Tags: webpack, babeljs, package.json, babel-loader

The error occurs when I run `babel src --out-dir lib --plugins=transform-function-bind,transform-regenerator`

I tried to re-install `transform-function-bind` but It still didn't work. I think the error occurs after I install webpack, but even though I uninstalled webpack I keep getting this error. I literally have no idea why this is happening. any ideas?